# Moving window with zip function in python

Tags: python, zip, iteration

I am missing something very simple. When I iterate over 5 elements with a zip function

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for i2,i1,i,i11,i22 in zip([None] + list[:-2], [None] + list[:-1], list, list[1:] + [None], list[2:] + [None]):
    print i2,i1,i,i11,i22
```

I get the result:

```
None None 1 2 3
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 4 5 6 7
5 5 6 7 None
```

So I am not sure why the element [:-2] gives me actually the element [:-1]. And also why it stops before the last line, I would imagine that the iteration ends with "5 6 7 None None". I guess these are some basics, but I've stuck. Any hints are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `list[:-2]` or `list[2:]`, you have to add 2 more elements to make the length of the new list same as list

By the way dont have the name of the variable same as `list`. Rename it to something as `lst`

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i2,i1,i,i11,i22 in zip([None, None] + lst[:-2], [None] + lst[:-1], lst, lst[1:] + [None], lst[2:] + [None, None]):
    print i2,i1,i,i11,i22
```

**Output:**

```
None None 1 2 3
None 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 None
5 6 7 None None
```

Comment: oh my! :) thanks a lot! yep, it is just for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Your lists are not the same length

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]


[print (i2,i1,i,i11,i22) for i2,i1,i,i11,i22 
 in zip([None,None]+ list[:-2], 
        [None] + list[:-1],
        list,
        list[1:] + [None],
        list[2:] + [None,None])]
```